# Angular: How to open angular variable in external browser - appgyver hybrid app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, appgyver

How do I add an angular variable into my controller function? I want to open links in my mobile app in external browser.

This currently works for me:

html:

`<button ng-click="openMenu()">Menu</button>`

controller.coffee:

```
.controller("ShowController", ($scope, City, supersonic) ->
    $scope.openMenu = function($scope) {
supersonic.app.openURL(“https://www.google.com“);
};
```

(The function is in javascript)

However, I need to open my angular variable {{city.menu.url}}, so this is what I placed in the html.

`<button ng-click="openMenu(city.menu.url)">Menu</button>`

But I don't know how to orient the javascript so that the `supersonic.app.openURL` opens the variable I specified in the html. Appreciate all answers.

Answer (score 0):

Change this `supersonic.app.openURL(“https://www.google.com“);`with:

```
$window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Inject `$window` in the controller

```
.controller("ShowController", ($scope, $window, City, supersonic) ->
    $scope.openMenu = function(url) {
        $window.location.href = url; //'http://www.google.com';
    };
```

Comment: I tried it but I think I'll have to use the supersonic.app.openURL to force the external browser to take over. 

http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/api-reference/stable/supersonic/app/openurl/